# JQuery UI DatePicker - Input Blocked when Calendar Overlays card-header

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, webforms, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have implemented JQuery UI Datepicker on a site.

I have an issue where that when I click to show the calendar dropdown, where the dropdown overlays the bootstrap card in the next row, anything over the card-header cannot be clicked on.

If I scroll the page, the calendar position remains static, but the non-clickable area moves to wherever the card-header is positioned.

[image: This Shows the unclickable area]

The z-index of the calendar is 9999, whilst that of the card-header is only 3.

I have tried adding

```
style="overflow: visible !important"
```

to the card based on another answer on stackoverflow, but no dice.

I have screenshot rendered html below, marking the datepicker, and the overlaid card-header:
[image: HTML Screenshot]

In case relevant, I am using:

- Bootstrap 4.6
- ASP.NET Webforms
- Material Dashboard 2.1.0
- JQuery UI 1.13.2
- JQuery 3.6.0

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to resolve? Thanks.

**Edit 1 - 2023-01-11**

I have put up a minimal example [Here](https://quickbooks.cerebrumsoftware.co.uk/errormwe/error.htm)

I have added an inline style to the card-header that is being overlaid to increase the height, so that the problem is more apparent.

(I have stripped out a load of script references for this example that are now causing a few console errors, but these are not related to the issue.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Twisty - thanks - I have added a link that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your code as it has links to content that is local to your web site. Consider the following more basic example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card z-index-2 mt-0 h-100">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Card with Datepicker</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-sm table-borderless mb-0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="pl-0 w-50 pt-1 pb-1 border-top-0" scope="row"><strong>Select Date</strong></th>
                <td class="pt-1 pb-1">
                  <span class="bmd-form-group is-filled"><input name="LastContactedCal" type="text" id="LastContactedCal" class="datepicker form-control" value="05/10/2022"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card z-index-2 mt-0 h-100">
      <div class="card-header" style="height: 200px;">
        <h4>Another Card</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Some Stuff</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works as expected without the issue that you reported. I suspect that some other component that my example is not using is interfering with the `click` event in your sites code. I would suggest you remove all additional libraries except for Bootstrap and jQuery UI, then add them back in one at a time or in other orders, to see when the functionality you are seeing returns.

Comment: OK, thanks. Turns out it is the CSS file material-dashboard that is causing the issue. Debugging again showed me it was the first thing I thought of - the z-index. I was sure the calendar z-index was 9999 when I first looked, but looking again it is only 1, and material-dashboard is setting the z-index of .card-header to 3 !important, so that element is in front of the calendar, but must be transparent. Marking as accepted answer as most helpful in resolving the issue. Thanks.